# Find the number of appointments booked for each treatment type

Tags: sql

Given these tables:

- DOCTOR (Doctor_ID, Surname, Specialization, Supervisor_ID, Address, Tel_No)
- APPOINTMENT (Doctor_ID, Dog_ID, Date, Time, Type_of_Treatment, Appointment_Length)
- PATIENT (Dog_ID, Breed, Sex, Name, Owner, Address)

Find the number of appointments booked for each treatment type.

Comment: This seems to be homework. Can you [edit] your question to explain what you tried and where you are stuck ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are actually looking for. The simple query will be

```
Select Type_of_Treatment, count(Type_of_Treatment) 
from APPOINTMENT 
group by Type_of_Treatment;
```